# Very high memory usage by Postgres 10.1 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

On Windows start up, ram usage is around 5% but it gradually keeps increasing and will eventually balloon to where it is using almost all the ram.The DB size is only 4941MB. The server has 8gb total memory and is a Xeon Quad core. The DB is on its own SSD drive. Below are the settings from my postgresql.conf file:

```
max_connections = 200           
shared_buffers = 512MB          
work_mem = 6553kB               
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = windows    
max_worker_processes = 4        
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2 
max_parallel_workers = 4        
wal_level = hot_standby
wal_buffers = 16MB          
max_wal_size = 2GB
min_wal_size = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7  
max_wal_senders = 5
wal_keep_segments = 32
max_replication_slots = 5
```

Below is a screenshot of Task Manager....
[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

If any other info is required i'll happily provide it.

Comment: How do you know the memory is used by Postgres? How many open Postgres connections do you have when the memory is all used up?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my post with a screenshot. Please take a look. This is the current situation.

Comment: I don't think the TaskManager gives an accurate information about the memory usage.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then what is task manager showing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986486/330315